# Can a quantum Field State be mathematically treated as a Superposition of "classical Setups" with Particles evolving according to path integrals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

In quantum Mechanics, a State of the System (a Wavefunction) can be understood as a "Superposition" of a continuum of different "classical States" (Positionings of the Particles) weighted with complex numbers.

The path integral formalism then leverages this, to compute the operator that describes the time evolution of the system, by computing its "Matrix elements" with respect to this "Basis" of classical placements of "point-particles", by integrating the action over all paths from classical placement a to classical placement b, for all choices of a and b.

Now the question is:

Can quantum field theories be described analogously?

So can the State ("Wavefunction") of a quantum Field be described as a superposition of a continuum of "classical setups" with some point-particles having fixed positions?

What about the path integral approach? How does this work for quantum fields?
(for quantum mechanics its clear what the paths are, classical trajectories of the involved particles leading the system from state a to state b, but how are the trajectories described mathematically when particles can just spring into existence and dissapear again or emit other particles?)

Or to sum it up: How can one formulate quantum Field theory using only "point-particle-action" (and superpositions), just like quantum mechanics can be formulated this way in the path integral formalism?

Comment: You may be interested in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation#Quantum_field_theory) entry on the functional integral formulation of QFT.

Comment: Seems like a good source, however I am still missing how the different "time evolutions" of the fields are to be represented. (What are the "paths" in QFT?)

Comment: I suppose these "Feynmann Diagrams" are sort of the paths I am looking for, but sadly I cannot find any resources explaining how exactly these diagrams are to be Interpreted as "paths" one can integrate over. (How do you define a measure on these diagrams?)

Comment: The paths in QFT are simply different field configurations. Feynman diagrams on the other side, come from the perturbative expansion of the $S$ matrix of the theory you are considering. One can obtain Feynman diagrams from functional integrals, as explained in this other [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram#Path_integral_formulation) entry.

Comment: Ok, so what are these field  configurations like? they cant be like classical fields evolving over time, because they have to be quantized...

Comment: Classical fields evolving over time are possible configurations of these fields. But these configurations are only the ones that contribute the most to the functional integral. In order to get all the possible configurations, you have to take into account every 'value' (scalar, spinor, vector, or tensor) at every point in space-time. This is why physicists generally write the measure of integration of the functional integral as the infinite product of measures for each point in space-time.

Comment: But how are Quantum fields quantized then? I mean this space of configurations is "continuous"...

Comment: The path integral *is* the quantization per se.